# fatal error using Win Bitcoin core to create node

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, installation

It ran about 10 hours, loaded 70% of blockchain, now always this error in debug.log on restart

2021-06-21T14:11:58Z ERROR: ReadBlockFromDisk: Errors in block header at FlatFilePos(nFile=1801, nPos=1334030)

2021-06-21T14:11:58Z *** Failed to read block

2021-06-21T14:11:58Z Error: A fatal internal error occurred, see debug.log for details

any suggestions ?? thx

Comment: Are you able to open that file manually? Try running a disk checker to look for bad sectors on the hard drive. Also check file permissions if they got changed somehow

Comment: yes the file blk01801.dat can be opened.  It's the last file created and smaller than the other .dat files

Comment: Hmm then I would try to scan for bad sectors.

Comment: disk is good.  am going to remove everything and start over using the ADMIN account instead of an account with admin priv

Comment: If this is windows you can right click the file and make sure the permissions are open so anyone can read and write

Comment: Deleted everything and started over using the win10 admin account instead of a user account and all is synced and node running after about 24 hours.  thx for input